# Ionic with Ubuntu 16.04 failure

Tags: ubuntu, ionic-framework, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to install ionic on my ubuntu 16.04.

After having it installed, I tried to run it with:

> ionic start --v2 myApp tabs

I get the following error:

```
******************************************************
 Dependency warning - for the CLI to run correctly,      
 it is highly recommended to install/upgrade the following:     

 Please install your Cordova CLI to version  >=4.2.0 `npm install -g cordova`

******************************************************
Creating Ionic app in folder /home/guy/myApp based on tabs project
Downloading: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic2-app-base/archive/master.zip
[=============================]  100%  0.0s
Downloading: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic2-starter-tabs/archive/master.zip
[=============================]  100%  0.0s
Installing npm packages...
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency @angular/tsc-wrapped@* included from @ionic/app-scripts will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency 
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency rxjs@* included from @ionic/app-scripts will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency 
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing fsevents@1.0.15
-
> node-sass@3.10.1 install /home/guy/myApp/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Start downloading binary at https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v3.10.1/linux-x64-46_binding.node
Binary downloaded and installed at /home/guy/myApp/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-46/binding.node

> node-sass@3.10.1 postinstall /home/guy/myApp/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

"/home/guy/myApp/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-46/binding.node" exists. 
 testing binary.
Binary is fine; exiting.
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-57-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.7.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.11
npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID

npm ERR! peerinvalid The package rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/core@2.2.1 wants rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/guy/myApp/npm-debug.log
Error with start undefined
Error Initializing app: There was an error with the spawned command: npminstall
There was an error with the spawned command: npminstall
```

================= UPDATE =================

I ran `ionic info` and got this:

```
******************************************************
 Dependency warning - for the CLI to run correctly,      
 it is highly recommended to install/upgrade the following:     

 Please install your Cordova CLI to version  >=4.2.0 `npm install -g cordova`

******************************************************

Your system information:

Cordova CLI:  You have been opted out of telemetry. To change this, run: cordova telemetry on.
6.4.0

Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.18
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.7
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Linux 4.4
Node Version: v4.7.0
Xcode version: Not installed


******************************************************
 Dependency warning - for the CLI to run correctly,      
 it is highly recommended to install/upgrade the following:     

 Please install your Cordova CLI to version  >=4.2.0 `npm install -g cordova`

******************************************************
```

However, I have already run `sudo npm install -g cordova` several times...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking deeper, I found an error during the instalation of cordova + ionic.
Then I found a hint - the problem might be an old npm version.

So I ran:

```
npm -g install npm
```

and... problem solved!!

Answer (score 0):

Give `sudo npm install -g cordova`

try this one

```
ionic start myApp tabs --v2
```

if still getting error

then please update your question with `ionic info`

Comment: I still get an error - `Error with start undefined
Error Initializing app: There was an error with the spawned command: npminstall` I will update my question as you asked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please install your Cordova CLI to version  >=4.2.0 `npm install -g cordova`

Open your terminal in Ubuntu (**Ctrl + Alt + T**)

Check your version of Cordova CLI
If < 4.2.0
Do `sudo npm install -g cordova`

Move to your ionic project folder

`cd <your project root folder>`

Then do

`sudo npm install`

`sudo npm update`

to make sure everything is up to date.

Then tell me if the error remains or not.

Comment: When I try `sudo npm install` I get error `npm ERR! install Couldn't read dependencies .... npm ERR! package.json ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/guy/package.json`

Comment: Hey @guyaloni I think you did not changed your directory to the project folder. Project folder is the folder that is created when you do `ionic start projectname --v2 tabs`. Check the updated instructions and see if it helps.

Comment: I have cordova version 6.4.0. It seems you ask me to lock the drawer and throw the key inside... how can I move to the project directory before creating it??

Answer (score 0):

I get the same error. What I do is just

```
ionic start myapp --v2
```

after that completes with the error, i go to

```
cd myapp
```

and run

```
npm install
```

then it works fine